# 14.0.4 LTS can not do anything

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center

I have a new distro of LTS Ubuntu on a 4 GB flash drive. Nothing has been installed because from minute 1 I can not download anything.

I have downloaded Teamviewer and can not install via Software center, it just has the install button, but when clicked does nothing.

The DPKG command can not find the file.

When running `apt-get upgrade` I get this error:

[image]

Here are the results for `df-h`

[image]

Internet is up and running and works just fine.
Flash was formatted with Rufus, I have also tried my CD boot of Ubuntu 15.04 (same issues) and also unetbooting boot on 32 GB flash drive.
same error...

Please help as I know there must be a root to all of these issues

Comment: Please post terminal output as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: 'Do you want to continue? [Y/n]' is not an error. It simply ask you if you want to install all the packages listed above the line '323 upgraded...'. And if you do, just type in y and Enter; or n and Enter if you don't.

Comment: But the stick does not contain that much space, can you explain why a brand new distro of Ubuntu would need that much space for upgrades?

Comment: not working.  should the file name be the full file name of

Comment: teamviewer_11.0.4.57095_i386.deb ?

I extracted the files to /Documents and get the following error...

Comment: root@ubuntu:~/Documents# sudo dpkg -i install teamviewer_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing archive install (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive teamviewer_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install  teamviewer_i386.deb

Answer (score 0):

There's no team-viewer package in Ubuntu repositories, you need to download the .deb file from their website and run these commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
```

And then if installation fails because of a dependency issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb
```

Comment: I extracted it to /Documents and did the same...
root@ubuntu:~# cd /home/Documents
bash: cd: /home/Documents: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~# cd /home
root@ubuntu:/home# cd /home/ubuntu/Documents
root@ubuntu:~/Documents# sudo dpkg -i install teamviewer_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing archive install (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive teamviewer_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install
 teamviewer_i386.deb

Comment: @JasonNewman Documents folder should be under /home/your username/Documents but I highly recommend you to install it without using terminal as root. Just use tilde character and cd into Documents using ~/Documents without being root user.

Comment: I think the 1st question should be, WHY does it want 24gb of space to upgrade or what is wrong about my formatting in my files

based on the df -h results

Comment: Ibattempted that as well and I had the same issue